# Banking Application pops up a browser window without toolbars. How to fix?

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox Quantum 58.0.

My banking application (here [CCP Connect Luxembourg](https://www.post.lu/en/particuliers/ccp/ccp-connect-application)) insists on popping up a completely unnecessary "undecorated window" (no toolbars or anything, on the other hand it has "facebook pixel" and "doubleclick ad exchange" trackers ... *kornheiser_why.jpg*) to prepare the user's login via 2-factor authentication. As I am using NoScript, and this window uses scripting, it stays blank, but I can't tell NoScript to whitelist this page as there is no NoScript icon on that window...

**Let me demonstrate:**

[image: The CCP Connect Login Screen]

**Click on "Login":**

[image: The CCP Connect Popup Window]

**Ouch time!**

*(The screenshot has a black border because I wanted to capture both windows overlaid, which means I need to "select a rectangle"; can't capture a window tree yet)*

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried using another browser? It this only happens on firefox it's very likely that the problem/solution is related to it and then the question could be better served on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, it's actually simple if you know how to. The key lies in this mozillaZone article: [Prevent websites from disabling new window features](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prevent_websites_from_disabling_new_window_features).

You have to tune the appropriate `dom. disable_window_open_feature.*` variable in `about:config`. There are quite a few:

- close: Prevents the close button from being disabled.
- directories: Prevents the bookmarks toolbar from being hidden.
- location: Prevents the address bar from being hidden
- menubar: Prevents the menubar from being hidden.
- minimizable: Prevents popup window minimization from being disabled.
- personalbar: Prevents the bookmarks toolbar from being hidden.
- resizable: Prevents popup window resizing from being disabled.
- scrollbars: Prevents the scrollbars on a popup from being disabled.
- status: Prevents the status bar from being hidden.
- titlebar: Prevents the title bar from being hidden.
- toolbar: Prevents the navigation toolbar from being hidden.

It's the last one which is of interest here. So let's search for it in the `about:config` screen and toggle it to true:

[image: Tune da Firefox, yo]

This will preclude the banking application from switching off the toolbar like it owns the place:

[image: We have a Toolbar]

We can then tell NoScript to allow scripts from previously unknown origins (https://secure.ccp-connect.lu and https://orely.luxtrust.com), which makes the 2-factor auth screen appear:

[image: A login screen appears, as it should]

Happy banking!